# Convolution2D "Depth of input is not a multiple of input depth of filter"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use fft2d transform in tensorflow and then analyse the magnitude and phase result with convolutional layers... I have made a system with Lambda layers to use tensorflow functions and get the magnitude and the phase. But when I add the Conv2d layer, I get the error

`Depth of input (3) is not a multiple of input depth of filter (199) for '1_Magn_Conv_f500_k2_2/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,199,199,3], [2,2,199,500]`

I don't understand what is the `shape [2,2,199,500]` and what is causing this error.

I have tried to reduce the number of layers in my networks to detect which one creates the problem. I have checked that magn_angle outputs two tensors with `shapes [None,199,199,3]`.
I am working with google colab.

Here is the minimal code to reproduce the error

```py
inpt = Input(shape = (199, 199, 3),name=str(0)+'_'+'Image')
def magn_angle(x):
    x = Lambda(lambda x:K.cast(x,dtype=tf.complex64))(x)
    x_list_magn = []
    x_list_angle = []
    for i in range(3):
        fft = Lambda(lambda x: tf.fft2d(x[:,:,:,i]), output_shape=(None,199,199))(x)# 2-dimensional discrete Fourier transform over the inner-most 2 dimensions
        x_list_magn.append(Lambda(lambda fft:K.expand_dims(tf.math.abs(fft),axis=-1), output_shape=(None,199,199))(fft))
        x_list_angle.append(Lambda(lambda fft: K.expand_dims(tf.math.angle(fft),axis=-1), output_shape=(None,199,199))(fft))
    magn = Concatenate()(x_list_magn)
    angle = Concatenate()(x_list_angle)
    magn = Lambda(lambda magn: K.cast(magn,dtype=tf.float32), output_shape=(None,199,199))(magn)
    angle = Lambda(lambda angle: K.cast(angle,dtype=tf.float32), output_shape=(None,199,199))(angle)
    return magn,angle
magn, angle = magn_angle(inpt)
magn = Conv2D(filters=500,kernel_size=(2,2),activation=None,strides=(1,1),padding='SAME',name=str(1)+'_'+'Magn_Conv_f500_k2',data_format="channels_last")(magn)
...
```

Which ouputs

`InvalidArgumentError: Depth of input (3) is not a multiple of input depth of filter (199) for '1_Magn_Conv_f500_k2_3/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,199,199,3], [2,2,199,500]`.

Comment: By fft do you mean fast fourier transform?

Comment: Yes, as on this website http://www.ejectamenta.com/Imaging-Experiments/fourierimagefiltering.html

Comment: Are you using tensorflow's implementation of the keras api? e.g. from tensorflow.keras.layers import ...

Comment: No I use directly keras

Comment: I ran your code without errors in a colab notebook using tf.keras - could be a version mismatch

Comment: It is working for me too. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I ran your code without errors in a colab notebook using tf.keras - could be a version mismatch – Colin Torney

Changing `keras. ...` imports to `tensorflow.keras. ...` has solved the problem.

Comment: I tried to change it to import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf tf.keras import layers.still have the error.