# Keras Custom Layer Receives same input shape every time

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I'm Writing OctConv Convolution layer in keras extending the keras layer, i've written the following code.

```py
import keras.backend as K

from keras.layers import Layer, UpSampling2D, Add, Concatenate, Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose

class OCTCONV_LAYER(Layer):
    def __init__(self,
            filters=16,
            kernel_size=(3, 3),
            strides=(2, 2),
            dilation_rate=(1, 1),
            padding='same',
            alpha_in=0.6,
            alpha_out=0.6,
            **kwargs
        ):
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.strides = strides
        self.padding = padding
        self.alpha_in = alpha_in
        self.alpha_out = alpha_out

        if dilation_rate[0] > 1:
            self.strides = (1, 1)

        self.dilation_rate = dilation_rate
        super(OCTCONV_LAYER, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        print('INPUT_SHAPE : {}'.format(input_shape))
        op_channels = self.filters
        low_op_channels = int(op_channels*self.alpha_out)
        high_op_channels = op_channels-low_op_channels

        inp_channels = input_shape[-1]
        low_inp_channels = int(inp_channels*self.alpha_in)
        high_inp_channels = inp_channels-low_inp_channels

        self.h_2_l = self.add_weight(
            name='hl',
            shape=self.kernel_size + (high_inp_channels, low_op_channels),
            initializer='he_normal'
        )
        self.h_2_h = self.add_weight(
            name='hh',
            shape=self.kernel_size + (high_inp_channels, high_op_channels),
            initializer='he_normal'
        )
        self.l_2_h = self.add_weight(
            name='lh',
            shape=self.kernel_size + (low_inp_channels, high_op_channels),
            initializer='he_normal'
        )
        self.l_2_l = self.add_weight(
            name='ll',
            shape=self.kernel_size + (low_inp_channels, low_op_channels),
            initializer='he_normal'
        )

        print('High 2 low : {}'.format(self.h_2_l.shape))
        print('High 2 high : {}'.format(self.h_2_h.shape))
        print('Low 2 high : {}'.format(self.l_2_h.shape))
        print('Low 2 low : {}'.format(self.l_2_l.shape))

        super(OCTCONV_LAYER, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        inp_channels = int(x.shape[-1])
        low_inp_channels = int(inp_channels*self.alpha_in)
        high_inp_channels = inp_channels-low_inp_channels

        high_inp = x[:,:,:, :high_inp_channels]
        print('High input shape : {}'.format(high_inp.shape))
        low_inp = x[:,:,:, high_inp_channels:]
        low_inp = K.pool2d(low_inp, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), pool_mode='avg')
        print('Low input shape : {}'.format(low_inp.shape))

        out_high_high = K.conv2d(high_inp, self.h_2_h, strides=(2, 2), padding='same')
        print('OUT HIGH HIGH shape : {}'.format(out_high_high.shape))
        out_low_high = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(K.conv2d(low_inp, self.l_2_h, strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
        print('OUT LOW HIGH shape : {}'.format(out_low_high.shape))
        out_low_low = K.conv2d(low_inp, self.l_2_l, strides=(2, 2), padding='same')
        print('OUT LOW LOW shape : {}'.format(out_low_low.shape))
        out_high_low = K.pool2d(high_inp, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), pool_mode='avg')
        out_high_low = K.conv2d(out_high_low, self.h_2_l, strides=(2, 2), padding='same')
        print('OUT HIGH LOW shape : {}'.format(out_high_low.shape))

        out_high = Add()([out_high_high, out_low_high])

        print('OUT HIGH shape : {}'.format(out_high.shape))

        out_low = Add()([out_low_low, out_high_low])

        out_low = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(out_low)

        print('OUT LOW shape : {}'.format(out_low.shape))

        out_final = K.concatenate([out_high, out_low], axis=-1)
        print('OUT SHAPE : {}'.format(out_final.shape))

        out_final._keras_shape = self.compute_output_shape(out_final.shape)

        return out_final

    def compute_output_shape(self, inp_shape):
        return inp_shape
```

To Create the layer and i'm using the following code to create the model

```py
from keras.layers import Input

inp = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = OCTCONV_LAYER(filters=16)(inp)
x = OCTCONV_LAYER()(x)
...
```

The Output On The Console Is,

[image]

As you can see, the input shape for the last layer is the same as the input layer, while the output shape of the first octconv layer is not the input shape.
What's wrong with the code? Am i missing something?

Comment: It's not really clear what you need. May be clean up the question by explaining what OctConv is supposed to do. and in the stack trace, point out to lines exactly you're referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code might be fine. There seem to be problems with [K.conv2d](https://keras.io/backend/#conv2d), as observed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893542/convolution2d-depth-of-input-is-not-a-multiple-of-input-depth-of-filter). One workaround to overcome this is to import keras from tensorflow (e.g. change all your `keras` imports to `tensorflow.keras`).

You will then need to make the following change:

```
low_inp_channels = int(int(inp_channels) * self.alpha_in)
high_inp_channels = int(inp_channels) - low_inp_channels
```

In this case, the input dimensionality of the second `OCTCONV_LAYER` corresponds to the output dimensionality of the first `OCTCONV_LAYER`. After the previous changes, the result is:

**First layer**

```
INPUT_SHAPE : (?, 224, 224, 3)
High 2 low : (3, 3, 2, 9)
High 2 high : (3, 3, 2, 7)
Low 2 high : (3, 3, 1, 7)
Low 2 low : (3, 3, 1, 9)
High input shape : (?, 224, 224, 2)
Low input shape : (?, 112, 112, 1)
OUT HIGH HIGH shape : (?, 112, 112, 7)
OUT LOW HIGH shape : (?, 112, 112, 7)
OUT LOW LOW shape : (?, 56, 56, 9)
OUT HIGH LOW shape : (?, 56, 56, 9)
OUT HIGH shape : (?, 112, 112, 7)
OUT LOW shape : (?, 112, 112, 9)
OUT SHAPE : (?, 112, 112, 16)
```

**Second layer**

```
INPUT_SHAPE : (?, 112, 112, 16)
High 2 low : (3, 3, 7, 9)
High 2 high : (3, 3, 7, 7)
Low 2 high : (3, 3, 9, 7)
Low 2 low : (3, 3, 9, 9)
High input shape : (?, 112, 112, 7)
Low input shape : (?, 56, 56, 9)
OUT HIGH HIGH shape : (?, 56, 56, 7)
OUT LOW HIGH shape : (?, 56, 56, 7)
OUT LOW LOW shape : (?, 28, 28, 9)
OUT HIGH LOW shape : (?, 28, 28, 9)
OUT HIGH shape : (?, 56, 56, 7)
OUT LOW shape : (?, 56, 56, 9)
OUT SHAPE : (?, 56, 56, 16)
```